# How To Handle White Space in Forloop from Dynamic Command to Create Directories

Tags: linux, bash, openstack

So I have a for loop that spits out the information I want (A list of OpenStack Projects), and I want it to make directories for me. However, sometimes, people name their projects with whitespaces in between and I need to account for it. Here is an example of the output from my command:

```
openstack project list
```

```
+----------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| ID                               | Name                                    |
+----------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| 0c1abff4e920448ba86638bd0d78f7ca | testing_grounds                         |
| 0dc5bed65a6b4a168c7531b1b4972e95 | Michaud                                 |
| 0eab4c57a6f34c01a0de65f433c1539c | Ansible Automation                      |
| 13d98b9d994c40029dcd2e9e4e38a26d | Sustaining Development                  |
| 2ec59a3a665946f4b9d5098d8562ebbb | Data Center Services                    |
| 379e46cbe60d420f977bf939ceed6961 | MF-DevStack                             |
| 63cecde0c0384e18a949247f03b8c490 | Kubernetes Labs                         |
| 677edd03e4ce439d884b017db19efd03 | mso-ems                                 |
| 6865e32d9f8646b6aa449f440f1a1bb1 | Network Development                     |
| 6a239dc6ce9c4fdca4ba2ef38849fa3b | Data Engineering                        |
| 71ceb6e4c5f14f168ec18c069b636c02 | Data Center Operations Service Scanning |
| 785f0b62484549048e6772e058bb0eb6 | admin                                   |
| 786b43df2b79470ea14da7468f9df1cc | service                                 |
| 7ca98362cb98428e9ad94c880f3efcae | OpenStack-Example                       |
| 89498a55aa374fb4915c5a08b903fc23 | Petes-place                             |
| 92c3fabbddb54e1696cffa223655c5d9 | Image Factory                           |
| 9f342bd754e748e7a20bd383eab9f47d | Network Automation                      |
| bdcba2785f334af5a2379f79d77f1308 | Fault and Performance Management        |
| cab8e3e810c24f29ace13ca3771cc41c | Microseg                                |
| cb41e6dea9744744a304c4ab77719062 | Development                             |
| ccf5970b1aa74f9ebb7a542b40110462 | Docker Enterprise                       |
| eb7d98031ec0407fb208b537a6888be5 | Application Architecture                |
| f33c8dd6acfc467aa05215a5fe8e7798 | casa-de-pedro                           |
+----------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

My command allows for me to actually specify the names only for this:

```
openstack project list -c Name -f value
```

Which looks like this:

```
testing_grounds
Michaud
Ansible Automation
Sustaining Development
Data Center Services
MF-DevStack
Kubernetes Labs
mso-ems
Network Development
Data Engineering
Data Center Operations Service Scanning
admin
service
OpenStack-Example
Petes-place
Image Factory
Network Automation
Fault and Performance Management
Microseg
Development
Docker Enterprise
Application Architecture
casa-de-pedro
```

So I thought about making a script that would collect all of the resources per project and sotre the resources in a directory labeled by the project name. So I thought about wrapping a for loop to make directories named after the project names. I have tried the following and they have not worked:

```
for i in $(openstack project list -c Name -f value); do mkdir -p -- 'echo $i'; done
for i in $(openstack project list -c Name -f value); do mkdir -p -- "$i"; done
for i in $(openstack project list -c Name -f value); do mkdir -p -- $i; done
```

none of them seem to really work and instead of incapsulating it in a string it doesn't work and instead still splits the names apart like `Network Development` becomes `Network` and `Development`. How can I get this to work so it will account for any whitespace that might exist within the project names.

Comment: `while IFS= read -r name; do echo mkdir -p "$name"; done < <(openstack project list -c Name -f value)` , Remove the echo if you're satisfied with the output.

Comment: I thought I already gave you the link about not `reading lines with for` and how to do it properly, yes?

Comment: lol yeah you did, I am really starting to hate for loops now and prefer this method better. I did try it earlier and it worked with this method but I had stored the output as a text file, Projects differ by cluster so I wanted to make it dynamic and not store it as a file but I guess I don't have a choice.

Comment: If it is a file then `done < file.txt` in the end instead of [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html).

Comment: yeah I was trying to use the command like such:

Comment: [openstack_backup]$ while IFS= read -r name; do mkdir -p "$name"; done < $(openstack project list -c Name -f value)

-bash: $(openstack project list -c Name -f value): ambiguous redirect

Comment: `< <(openstack project list -c Name -f value)` Note it will  not work with `sh` and the likes. Since it is a bash feature (maybe some other shell)

Comment: that worked for me `while IFS= read -r name; do mkdir -p "$name"; done < <(openstack project list -c Name -f value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So unfortunately I couldn't use the regular for-loop syntax to achieve this. Instead I had to use a while loop (many thanks to [Jetchisel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4452265/jetchisel) on helping me acheive this outcome).
The following method worked for me:

```
[openstack_backup]$ while IFS= read -r name; do mkdir -p "$name"; done < <(openstack project list -c Name -f value)
[openstack_backup]$ ls
admin                     Data Center Operations Service Scanning  Docker Enterprise                 MF-DevStack  Network Automation   service
Ansible Automation        Data Center Services                     Fault and Performance Management  Michaud      Network Development  Sustaining Development
Application Architecture  Data Engineering                         Image Factory                     Microseg     OpenStack-Example    testing_grounds
casa-de-pedro             Development                              Kubernetes Labs                   mso-ems      Petes-place
```

Answer (score 1):

You would be better with output in JSON format and parse it with `jq`

`openstack project list --long -f json`

Or use a more appropriate language like python.